# How to map an API with Typescript in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mapping

I'm new to Typescript and I have to get a list of books from an API. My profesor gave me the code in javascript to do this, but I have to do this in typescript and react native.

**Getting api:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1"
});

export default api;
```

**List component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './List.css';

class List extends Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        const apiData = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="List">
                {apiData?.map(item => (
                <div className="Livro">
                    <h3> {item.name}</h3>
                    <p> {item.authors.join(',')}</p>
                    <p><a href={item.url} target='_blank' rel="noreferrer"> {item.url}</a></p>
                </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

**An example how I will call the List component:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import List from '../../components/list'
import api from '../../_config/api';
import './Welcome.css';

class Welcome extends Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {sectionData:props.sectionData}
    this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }
  
  async fetchData(value) {

    const response = await api.get('/books?name='+value)

    this.setState({sectionData:response?.data})
    
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData('');
  }

  render() { 
    const {sectionData} = this.state;


    return (
        <div className="Welcome">
             <List data={sectionData}/>
        </div>
      );
      
  }

}

export default Welcome;
```

**The part of the code that only works in Javascript:**

```js
return (
            <div className="List">
                {apiData?.map(item => (  // error here
                <div className="Livro">
                    <h3> {item.name}</h3>
                    <p> {item.authors.join(',')}</p>
                    <p><a href={item.url} target='_blank' rel="noreferrer"> {item.url}</a></p>
                </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
```

I tried to do this the same way in typescript, but it return this error:

> Type error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Is there any way to resolve this error or another way to map an API without using map()?

Comment: It seems like you're assuming the props will be an array, which isn't true, but without a [mre] it's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating an interface for your `List` component, and put the interface on your component like below.

```js
interface IListProps {
 apiData?: { name: string, authors: string[], url: string }[];
}

interface IListState {}

class List extends Component<IListProps, IListState> {
// your code...
}
```

I also see that your `props` on the `List` component inside the `render` of the `Welcome` component are wrong.

```js
interface IWelcomeProps {
  sectionData?: { name: string, authors: string[], url: string }[];
}

interface IWelcomeState {}

class Welcome extends Component<IWelcomeProps, IWelcomeState> {  
  // your code...

  render() {
    const { sectionData } = this.state; 
    return (
        <div className="Welcome">
             <List apiData={sectionData}/> // replace data by apiData
        </div>
      );
      
  }

}
```

You can find more info about how to use interfaces [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html).

Comment: I tried it now, but doesn't works, I don't know why.

Comment: This is good but your State interface is pointless and meaningless. It's interchangeable with the Props interface it extends.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you for your advice. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from xZliman idea, I researched and get no error when doind this:

```
class List extends Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        const apiData = this.props as {name: string, authors: string[], url: string}[]; // Here is the change

        return (
            <div className="List">
                {apiData.map(item => (
                <div className="Livro">
                    <h3> {item.name}</h3>
                    <p> {item.authors.join(',')}</p>
                    <p><a href={item.url} target='_blank' rel="noreferrer"> {item.url}</a></p>
                </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

Maybe it isn't a good solution, but it gets the work done as a workaround.